# How to find a basis of pure sinusoids

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, change-of-basis

I have this little question: Imagine some set of let's say 10 sinusoids, defined on the same interval (all with different frequencies, amplitudes, phases).

Then a friend gives you a linear combination of those sinusoids, not the sinusoids themselves. How can you retrieve them?

My question is then how can you find the most "pure" functions. I am wondering if there is some quantity that a function minimizes if it is a pure sinusoid instead of a sum of different sinusoids, and maybe that allows to find the transformation matrix needed to get back to the original sinusoids.

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: What do you mean he "gives you a linear combination"? The value(s) of a linear combination at some point(s)?

Comment: Do you know the "$10$ sinusoids" in the initial set?

Comment: Sorry I should have said that, yes I mean values at regularly spaced points, he gives me a vector on Matlab actually that rascal friend. 
And I don't know the initial sinusoids.

Comment: A fast fourier transform (FFT) in matlab might isolate the frequencies in your linear combinations.

Comment: Yes indeed, but isn't there a way to directly obtain the transformation matrix, by some kind of linear algebra argument?